# Why is my function unable to return elements with specific text content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have a function, matchTagAndText which as the name says accepts 2 arguments a selector and text and checks if any of the matched elements has the given text. It goes like so:

```
function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
        return RegExp(txt,'i').test(element.textContent);
    });
}
```

Now I am trying to select a `td` element which contains text 'Lorem ipsum' in it but I am unable to do so.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frames</title>
</head>
<body>
    <td colspan="2" class="font-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nulla iste, quae necessitatibus. Impedit mollitia delectus eum voluptas ullam! Perspiciatis in dolorem blanditiis dolores mollitia sint nostrum sunt veniam est!
    </td>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried calling the function after defining it in console with:

```
var el = matchTagAndText('td.font-description','Lorem ipsum');
```

But this returns an empty array. What is wrong with my function?

Live Example:

```js
function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
        return RegExp(txt,'i').test(element.textContent);
    });
} 

var el = matchTagAndText('td.font-description','Lorem ipsum');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<td colspan="2" class="font-description">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nulla iste, quae necessitatibus. Impedit mollitia delectus eum voluptas ullam! Perspiciatis in dolorem blanditiis dolores mollitia sint nostrum sunt veniam est!
</td>
```

Comment: NB: you can use `[].filter.call(elements, ...)` as a shortcut for `Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, ...)`

Comment: @Alnitak Shorter, but unnecessarily creates an array. `Array.prototype.filter.call` feels cleaner since it’s more direct.

Comment: @Xufox fair point, although code that makes repeated calls could retain a single reference to that function though meaning that the total overhead is negligible (and offset by the potential gains in not dereferencing that property chain for every call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem, intriguingly, is that your markup is invalid: You have `td` with no surrounding `tr` or `table`. If you fix that, it works:

```js
function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
        return RegExp(txt,'i').test(element.textContent);
    });
} 

var el = matchTagAndText('td.font-description','Lorem ipsum');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="font-description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nulla iste, quae necessitatibus. Impedit mollitia delectus eum voluptas ullam! Perspiciatis in dolorem blanditiis dolores mollitia sint nostrum sunt veniam est!
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If we inspect your example using Chrome's devtools, we can see that in its attempt to make the HTML valid, it's just completely stripped your `td` tag, and its associated `class`, so your selector doesn't match anything:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, your markup is not - A TD should live inside a row inside a table.

```js
function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element) {
    return RegExp(txt, 'i').test(element.textContent);
  });
}

var el = matchTagAndText('td.font-description','Lorem ipsum');

console.log(el);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="font-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nulla iste, quae necessitatibus. Impedit mollitia delectus eum voluptas ullam! Perspiciatis in dolorem blanditiis dolores mollitia sint nostrum sunt veniam est!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with your HTML. You cannot write an HTML document that contains a  element outside a  element. Browser will simply not construc such element and in resoult you cannot select it.

```js
function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    console.log(elements)
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
        return RegExp(txt,'i').test(element.textContent);
    });
} 

var el = matchTagAndText('td','Lorem ipsum');

console.log(el);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frames</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
      <td colspan="2" class="font-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nulla iste, quae necessitatibus. Impedit mollitia delectus eum voluptas ullam! Perspiciatis in dolorem blanditiis dolores mollitia sint nostrum sunt veniam est!
      </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550334/why-is-my-function-unable-to-return-elements-with-specific-text-content#
```